# Fill MovieClip with webcam output in Haxe

Tags: flash, haxe

I'm trying to build a simple Flash SWF with Haxe that shows the output of my webcam. I want the SWF to be embeddable and the size to be determined in the HTML. So my HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<head><title>Web cam</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#dddddd">
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
    id="haxe"
    align="middle"
    width="640" height="480">
<param name="movie" value="webcam.swf"/>
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="scale" value="exactfit" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"/>
<embed src="webcam.swf"
       width="640" height="480"
       bgcolor="#ffffff"
       name="haxe"
       quality="high"
       align="middle"
       allowScriptAccess="always"
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"
/>
</object>
</body>
</html>
```

This should put a webcam.swf of a size of 640x480. To build `webcam.swf` I use the following Haxe script:

```
class Webcam {
    static function main() {
          var mc : flash.display.MovieClip;
          var rawvideo : flash.media.Video;
          var cam:flash.media.Camera = flash.media.Camera.getCamera();
          cam.setMode(320, 240, 24, false);
          cam.setQuality(0, 100);

          mc=flash.Lib.current;
          var stage = flash.Lib.current.stage;
          stage.scaleMode=flash.display.StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
          rawvideo = new flash.media.Video(Std.int(stage.width), Std.int(stage.height) );
          rawvideo.attachCamera(cam);

          if (cam!=null) {
            mc.addChild(rawvideo);
          } else {
            trace("No Camera");
          }
    }    
}
```

This creates the SWF file that shows the webcam output but with some big white bands on the right and bottom. I want the webcam image to fill the entire Flash object. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For future reference: looks like changing camera mode changes the size of the video control. Finding the correct video mode for the camera was the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I have had no success getting your code to work at 640x480.

To get it to work at 320x240 change the line:

```
stage.scaleMode=flash.display.StageScaleMode.EXACT_FIT;
```

to

```
stage.scaleMode=flash.display.StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

And change the resolution to 320x240 in the HTML.